# How to run docker image in Kubernetes (v1.21) pod for CI/CD scenario?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-pipelines, azure-aks

We're investigating using an AKS cluster to run our Azure Pipeline Agents.

I've looked into tools like Kaniko for building docker images, which should work fine, however some of our pipelines run docker commands, e.g. we run [checkov](https://github.com/bridgecrewio/checkov) using the docker image, but I've struggled to find any solution that seems to work, given the deprecation of the docker shim in kubernetes.

The obvious solution would be add those tools that we currently run from docker into our agent image but this isn't a great solution as it will mean that any time a developer wants to run a tool like that we would need to modify the new image, which is less than ideal.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [nerdctl](https://github.com/containerd/nerdctl) or [crictl](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/cri-tools/blob/master/docs/crictl.md) for your commands and even create an alias for that (specially wiht nerdctl) = `alias docker="nerdctl"`

As docker images or better said container images using the OCI image format you will have no issues running them with containerd or cri-o.